# She sets off for India or She set off for India

Tags: grammatical-number

I want to say she's going on a journey with the words "set off". Should it be 1 or 2?

1. She sets off for India.
2. She set off for India.

Comment: This isn't a question of grammatical number, but of tense.

Comment: Detail: She didn't do it in the past, and she's not doing it at the moment but she's decided and is about to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She sets off for India is correct.

She set off would imply that you're talking about a past event. However you said she "is going" to India, so I don't assume that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

"She sets off for India" is present (imperfect), implying that it happens continually.  That would not make sense here.  It could also be historical present, past tense told in present tense to make it more dramatic.  I don't think that is what you want either.

"She set off for India" is past tense.

"She is setting off for India" is present progressive, implying that it is happening at this moment.

They are a few other tenses, but I think one of the last two is want you are looking for.

Comment: She is setting off for India would be better to express that it's happening at this very moment - I agree. I however think that "She sets off for India tomorrow/next week.." would be valid? I assumed that the OP meant that she's going to India in the near future.